# Optimising number of queries within a DRF ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Within Django Rest Framework's serialiser it is possible to add more data to the serialised object than in the original Model.
This is useful for when calculating statistical information, on the server-side, and adding this extra information when responding to an API call.

As I understand, adding extra data is done using a `SerializerMethodField`, where each field is implemented by a `get_...` function.
However, if you have a number of these SerializerMethodFields, each one can be querying the Model/database separately, for what might be essentially the same data.

**Is it possible to query the database once, store the list/result as a data member** of the ModelSerializer object, and use the result of the queryset in many functions?

Here's a very simple example, just for illustration:

```
############## Model

class Employee(Model):
    SALARY_TYPE_CHOICES = (('HR', 'Hourly Rate'), ('YR', 'Annual Salary'))
    salary_type = CharField(max_length=2, choices=SALARY_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=False)
    salary = PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    company = ForeignKey(Company, related_name='employees')

class Company(Model):
    name = CharField(verbose_name='company name', max_length=100)


############## View

class CompanyView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    lookup_field='id'
    serializer_class = CompanySerialiser

class CompanyListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerialiser


############## Serializer

class CompanySerialiser(ModelSerializer):
    number_employees = SerializerMethodField()
    total_salaries_estimate = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name',
                  'number_employees',
                  'total_salaries_estimate',
                 ]
    def get_number_employees(self, obj):
        return obj.employees.count()
    def get_total_salaries_estimate(self, obj):
        employee_list = obj.employees.all()
        salaries_estimate = 0
        HOURS_PER_YEAR = 8*200 # 8hrs/day, 200days/year
        for empl in employee_list:
            if empl.salary_type == 'YR':
                salaries_estimate += empl.salary
            elif empl.salary_type == 'HR':
                salaries_estimate += empl.salary * HOURS_PER_YEAR
        return salaries_estimate
```

The Serialiser can be optimised to:

- use an object data member to store the result from the query set,
- only retrieve the queryset once,
- re-use the result of the queryset for all extra information provided in SerializerMethodFields.

Example:

```
class CompanySerialiser(ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanySerialiser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.employee_list = None

    number_employees = SerializerMethodField()
    total_salaries_estimate = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name',
                  'number_employees',
                  'total_salaries_estimate',
                 ]
    def _populate_employee_list(self, obj):
        if not self.employee_list: # Query the database only once.
            self.employee_list = obj.employees.all()
    def get_number_employees(self, obj):
        self._populate_employee_list(obj)
        return len(self.employee_list)
    def get_total_salaries_estimate(self, obj):
        self._populate_employee_list(obj)
        salaries_estimate = 0
        HOURS_PER_YEAR = 8*200 # 8hrs/day, 200days/year
        for empl in self.employee_list:
            if empl.salary_type == 'YR':
                salaries_estimate += empl.salary
            elif empl.salary_type == 'HR':
                salaries_estimate += empl.salary * HOURS_PER_YEAR
        return salaries_estimate
```

This works for the single retrieve `CompanyView`.  And, in fact saves one query/context-switch/round-trip to the database; I've eliminated the "count" query.

However, it does **not work** for the list view `CompanyListView`, because it seems that the serialiser object is created once and reused for each Company.  So, only the first Company's list of employees is stored in the objects "`self.employee_list`" data member, and thus, all other companies erroneously get given the data from the first company.

Is there a best practice solution to this type of problem?  Or am I just wrong to use the ListAPIView, and if so, is there an alternative?

Comment: Really?  Downvoted immediately after I posted this question, without any comment?

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue can be solved if you can pass the queryset to the `CompanySerialiser` with data already fetched.

You can do the following changes

```
class CompanyListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.all().prefetch_related('employee_set')
    serializer_class = CompanySerialiser`
```

And instead of count use `len` function because count does the query again.

```
class CompanySerialiser(ModelSerializer):
    number_employees = SerializerMethodField()
    total_salaries_estimate = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'name',
                  'number_employees',
                  'total_salaries_estimate',
                 ]
    def get_number_employees(self, obj):
        return len(obj.employees.all())
    def get_total_salaries_estimate(self, obj):
        employee_list = obj.employees.all()
        salaries_estimate = 0
        HOURS_PER_YEAR = 8*200 # 8hrs/day, 200days/year
        for empl in employee_list:
            if empl.salary_type == 'YR':
                salaries_estimate += empl.salary
            elif empl.salary_type == 'HR':
                salaries_estimate += empl.salary * HOURS_PER_YEAR
        return salaries_estimate
```

Since the data is prefetched, serializer will not do any additional query for `all`. But make sure you are not doing any kind of filter because another query will execute in that case.

Comment: I like your answer, I wasn't aware of prefetching.  However, I think this might not be enough for more complex scenarios.  For example, what if "Company" also has a relationship to a second/third/fourth/etc model?  Can I do multiple prefetches somehow?  BUT, I'd still prefer if there is a solution where the object can hold information/data-members specific to any one object being serialised, that way it would be more generic and capable of storing any information, not just database queried results.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ritesh Agrawal, you simply need to prefetch the data. However, I advise to do the aggregations directly inside the database instead of using Python:

```
class CompanySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    number_employees = IntegerField()
    total_salaries_estimate = FloatField()

    class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = ['id', 'name',
              'number_employees',
              'total_salaries_estimate', ...
             ]

class CompanyListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Company.objects.annotate(
       number_employees=Count('employees'),
       total_salaries_estimate=Sum(
           Case(
               When(employees__salary_type=Value('HR'),
                    then=F('employees_salary') * Value(8 * 200)
               ),
               default=F('employees__salary'),
               output_field=IntegerField() #optional a priori, because you only manipulate integers
           )
        )
    )
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

Notes:

- I haven't tested this code, but I'm using the same kind of syntax for my own projects. If you encounter errors (like 'cannot determine type of output' or similar), try wrapping `F('employees_salary') * Value(8 * 200)` inside an `ExpressionWrapper(..., output_field=IntegerField())`.
- Using aggregation, you can apply filters on the queryset afterwards. However, if you're prefetching your related `Employee`s, then you cannot filter the related objects anymore (as mentioned in the previous answer). BUT, if you already know you'll need the list of employees with hourly rate, you can do `.prefetch_related(Prefetch('employees', queryset=Employee.object.filter(salary_type='HR'), to_attr="hourly_rate_employees"))`.

Relevant documentation: 
[Query optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/#do-database-work-in-the-database-rather-than-in-python)
[Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

Hope this will help you ;)